# this.options is undefined. I dont have any field called this.options

Tags: vue.js

Im working on a project, and Vue has been driving me nuts. For some reason, no matter what I try, I keep getting the error

```
    new Vue.component('interactbutton',{
        template:'<input type="file" id="Step1Image" placeholder="Step 1 Image...">'
})
    new Vue({
        el:"#MainViewPortApp"
    })
```

My HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="Js/VueApps.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainViewPortApp">

        <interactbutton></interactbutton>


    </div>



</body>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>




</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Vue.component` is not a constructor. Do not use `new` with it.

Comment: So how does one instantiate a component in vue.js?

Comment: @alex `Vue.extend` returns a constructor.
https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/